# react-hook-form use in component to pass props for dynamic text fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-forms

**Original question**

I have the following component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function FormField({ type, name, formRegister, errorMsg, state }) {
  const methods = useForm();
  const { register } = methods;

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={name} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
          Password
        </label>

        <div className="mt-1">
          <input
            type={type}
            name={name}
            {...register({ formRegister }, { required: { errorMsg } })}
            className="py-3 px-4 block w-full shadow-sm text-gray-900 focus:ring-blue-700 focus:border-blue-900 border-gray-300 rounded-md"
            onChange={(event) => {state}(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

FormField.PropTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  formRegister: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  errorMsg: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  state: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

FormField.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  name: 'text',
  formRegister: 'text',
  errorMsg: 'text is required',
  state: 'setName'
};
```

My goal for this component is to create a dynamic field component so I can do the following

```
<FormField
  type="password"
  name="password"
  formRegister="password"
  errorMsg="Password is required"
  state="setPassword"
/>
```

However, I'm having issues in passing in the react-form-hooks `...register`

I get the following

```
TypeError: path.split is not a function
```

Any help would be great, cheers.

**original edit**

So the forms are now working thanks too knoefel, however, here is the issue, the error messages are now not showing.

So in my component I have everything needed for errors to be passed, however they are not showing, debugging this I've found that when I do this

```
<FormField
  {...register(email, { required: 'email is required' })}
  type="email"
  label="Email"
  name="email"
  errorMsg="Email is required"
  placeholder="john.doe@ebrookes.dev"
/>
```

The error now shows, so what gives? I already have this in the component?

**Updated question #2**

I now have the following component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const FormField = React.forwardRef(
  ({ type, name, label, required, placeholder, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={name} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
          {label}
          <span className="text-red-500 font-bold text-lg">{required && '*'}</span>
        </label>

        <div className="mt-1">
          <input
            {...props}
            name={name}
            ref={ref}
            type={type}
            id={name}
            className={['field', `field--${type}`].join(' ')}
            placeholder={placeholder}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default FormField;

FormField.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(['text', 'email', 'password', 'file', 'checkbox']),
  register: PropTypes.func,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string
};

FormField.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  name: 'text',
  label: 'Label',
  placeholder: ''
};
```

and now the following page

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Background from '../../../public/images/option1.png';
import Router from 'next/router';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/client';
import { useForm, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';

// components
import ErrorsPopup from '../../components/ErrorsPopup';
import FormField from '../../components/Forms/FormField';
import Button from '../../components/Button';

export default function Login() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const { handleSubmit, register } = methods;

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      data
    });

    Router.push('/dashboard');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Ellis Development - Login</title>
      </Head>

      <div className="relative">
        <div className="md:flex">
          {/* Image */}
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-700 h-screen lg:w-96">
            <Image src={Background} width={350} height={350} layout="fixed" />
          </div>

          {/* Contact form */}
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center px-6 sm:px-10 w-full">
            <h1 className="text-4xl font-extrabold text-grey-800">Login</h1>

            {/* errors */}
            <FormProvider {...methods}>
              <ErrorsPopup />
            </FormProvider>

            <form
              onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="mt-6 flex flex-col gap-y-6 sm:gap-x-8">
              {/* email field */}
              <FormField
                {...register('email', {
                  required: 'Email is required',
                  pattern: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i
                })}
                type="email"
                label="Email"
                placeholder="john.doe@ebrookes.dev"
                required
              />

              {/* password field */}
              <FormField
                {...register('password', {
                  required: 'Password is required'
                })}
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                placeholder="*******"
                required
              />

              <div className="flex items-center justify-between sm:col-span-2">
                <div>
                  <Button type="submit" label="Login" icon="SaveIcon" />
                </div>

                <div>
                  <Link href="/dashboard/auth/register">
                    <a className="underline decoration-blue-500 decoration-4 hover:decoration-2 mr-4">
                      Register
                    </a>
                  </Link>

                  <Link href="/dashboard/auth/forgot">
                    <a className="underline decoration-blue-500 decoration-4 hover:decoration-2">
                      Forgot your password?
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue here now is that the form is still not submitting.

Any help would be great, cheers.

**edit #2**

This is what I get when submitting the form and also added `console.log(formState.errors)`
[image]

Also when I fill the form out I get no errors, so could the issue be around on the onSubmit?.

Also if I console log the data I get this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a working CodeSandbox after your last update of your question. You forgot to set the name prop of your `<input />`, so RHF had no chance to access the form fields. You also don't need `useState` here, as you can just access the form data in the callback of `handleSubmit`.

You could also simplify your interface by using your `name` prop as the first argument for your `register` call. The spread of `register` will also [return](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/8aab57a1930e99aa8641da2e8bf031b55929dd6d/src/logic/createFormControl.ts#L916) a `name` property set to the name of the first argument you pass to `register`.

```js
export default function Login() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const { handleSubmit, register } = methods;

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Ellis Development - Login</title>
      </Head>

      <div className="relative">
        <div className="md:flex">
          {/* Image */}
          <div className="flex items-center justify-center bg-blue-700 h-screen lg:w-96"></div>

          {/* Contact form */}
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center px-6 sm:px-10 w-full">
            <h1 className="text-4xl font-extrabold text-grey-800">Login</h1>
            <FormProvider {...methods}>{/* errors */}</FormProvider>

            <form
              onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
              className="mt-6 flex flex-col gap-y-6 sm:gap-x-8"
            >
              {/* email field */}
              <FormField
                {...register("email", {
                  required: "Email is required",
                  pattern: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i
                })}
                type="email"
                label="Email"
                placeholder="john.doe@ebrookes.dev"
                required
              />

              {/* password field */}
              <FormField
                {...register("password", {
                  required: "Email is required"
                })}
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                placeholder="*******"
                required
              />

              <div className="flex items-center justify-between sm:col-span-2">
                <div>
                  <input type="submit" label="Login" />
                </div>

                <div>
                  <Link href="/dashboard/auth/register">
                    <a className="underline decoration-blue-500 decoration-4 hover:decoration-2 mr-4">
                      Register
                    </a>
                  </Link>

                  <Link href="/dashboard/auth/forgot">
                    <a className="underline decoration-blue-500 decoration-4 hover:decoration-2">
                      Forgot your password?
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
const FormField = forwardRef(
  ({ type, name, label, required, placeholder, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label
          htmlFor={name}
          className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
        >
          {label}
          <span className="text-red-500 font-bold text-lg">
            {required && "*"}
          </span>
        </label>

        <div className="mt-1">
          <input
            {...props}
            name={name}
            ref={ref}
            type={type}
            id={name}
            className={["field", `field--${type}`].join(" ")}
            placeholder={placeholder}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

[image: Edit NextJS 10 + Tailwind 2.0 (forked)]

Comment: Ah so I was accidentally setting two objects instead of one?

Comment: Yes. The signature of `register` expects as the first parameter a string and as the second parameter the rules object. Check the docs [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) for more infos. You also should set your `errorMsg` directly to `required` Not via an object. Or otherwise you need to rename it `message`  There is also an example in the docs for the same section.

Comment: Can you provide an example to the errorMsg cause, because after changing over the fields to the new component the error messages no longer popup.

Comment: From the docs for required: A Boolean which, if true, indicates that the input must have a value before the form can be submitted. You can assign a string to return an error message in the errors object.

Comment: Example: <input
  {...register("test", {
    required: 'error message'
  })}
/>

Comment: It’s the same format as in my answer above.

Comment: So I have to set the {...register ...} on each field individually? There's no way to pass that through using the component?

Comment: I've added an edit to the question @knoefel

Comment: Please post also your updated <FormField /> component in your question.

Comment: I've created an updated question

Comment: Did you wrap your component in the `<form />` tag and also use `handleSubmit` from RHF? Something like in this [example](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started).

Comment: I've edited the updated question to show the full page code

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a working codesandbox.

Comment: Does it have form errors? Please check by logging RHF's `formState.errors`.

Comment: I've added a screenshot and a capture of the errors when there are any

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you can submit the form, as it prints out the fields with its values. So what is not working? I'm having trouble understanding whats wrong.